# Why does my applet have warning signs?

Tags: java, security, digital-signature, japplet

For some reason beyond my knowledge, my applet is displaying these little warning signs every time I interact with one of its controls.

This does not happen when I use Applet Viewer, so I assume that this is happening since it's not signed.

What is the reason and purpose for this annoying behavior, if this problem is exclusive to unsigned applets?

Also, is it possible to remove these signs?

[image]

Comment: Is the applet signed?

Comment: Health and safety gone mad...

Comment: @MadProgrammer No, the applet is not signed. Also, there is no way this could be happening due to my code.

Comment: That is likely your answer

Comment: @MadProgrammer Well, I would like an explanation of why unsigned applets behave like this. What in the world could be the reason?

Comment: Because, that's how try work. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/appletwarning-135102.html

Comment: The intention is to ensure that "dumb" users don't accidentally provide more functionality to an applet that hasn't been signed and they can identify that a window has been generated by the applet itself. This has been a key feature of applets since there creation. The main reason you know get a warning icon, as apposed to the old border decorations is two fold. It's easier to identify and provide feedback and two, under some circumstances, it was possible to remove these decorations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a Java "feature" for letting users know that it is a Java Applet window.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/appletwarning-135102.html#6u12

The link also shows how to change the positioning of the warning sign.

Even my signed applets show this warning sign.

I found that my signed applet warning sign disappears if you set the applet to use all-permissions (instead of sandbox).
But that's not exactly recommended.
To change the applet to use all-permissions, edit the jar's MANIFEST.MF to have the line
`Permissions: all-permissions` instead of sandbox.

Comment: What else should I do to remove these signs?